# extract key=value from string with batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have following data in a text file and I want value of `name`.

Text file contents:

> ```
> package: name='com.package.addres' versionCode='35' versionName='1.8.0 (RC)' compileSdkVersion='23' compileSdkVersionCodename='6.0-2438415'
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your text file content is all in a single line, and on the first line of the file:

```batch-file
@Set /P "name=" 0< "mytextfile.txt"
@Set "name=%name:*name=%"
@Set "name=%name:~2%"
@Set "name=%name:'="&:"%"
@Echo %name% & Pause
```

*Just replace the name of your text file on line `1` as needed, (`mytextfile.txt`).*

If you were positive that `name='value'` will always be the first listed, you could also use a [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop):

```batch-file
@For /F "UseBackTokens=2Delims='" %%G In ("mytextfile.txt")Do @Set "name=%%G" 
@Echo %name% & Pause
```

Comment: what if i had a next line or what if i wanted another `key` , what will change ? I am not familiar with batch scripting . thank you in advance . I am using `For-loop` BTW it's seems cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

This solution extracts *all variables* from the data line:

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Read the data line from the file
for /F "tokens=1*" %%a in (test.txt) do set "data=%%b"

rem Extract all variables
set "%data:' ='" & set "%"

rem For example:
echo name=%name%
echo versionName=%versionName%
echo compileSdkVersionCodename=%compileSdkVersionCodename%
```

Output example:

```
name='com.package.addres'
versionName='1.8.0 (RC)'
compileSdkVersionCodename='6.0-2438415'
```

You may use a `skip=#` option in `FOR` command (followed by `goto continue`) in order to read another line.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `For` loop:

```
@for /f "tokens=2*" %%i in (in.txt) do @set "key=%%i"
@set "%key:'=%"
@echo %name%
```